# How can a nested ScrollView expand to 100% its height in React Native?

Tags: react-native, view, scrollview

I have a main ScrollView for a user profile, and then within that ScrolllView I call a component that is also a ScrollView with the same vertical orientation.

I'm looking to expand the nested component so its height is 100% of the content within it. Currently, the height appears to be around the height of the screen, while the content within it appears to be much longer.

The code I currently have looks like this:

```
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }} contentContainerStyle={{ marginTop: HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT, paddingBottom: HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT * 1.5 }}>   

     ...irrelevant code here

     {showSub && <Sub uid={uid} /> }

</ScrollView>
```

Where Sub is broadly defined as this, I've removed some unnecessary code from this example:

```
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}
            contentContainerStyle={{ marginTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 }}
            scrollEventThrottle={2}
            onScroll={this.onScroll} 
            refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={this.onRefresh} />}
      > 

      ...irrelevant code here

            <View>
                    {categories && Object.keys(categories).map((category, catIndex) => {
                        let currentCategory = categories[category]
                        let collections = currentCategory['data']
                        let categoryName = currentCategory['categoryName']

                        return (
                            <View key={category}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={{ flex: 1 }} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Category', { category })}>
                         <Text style={{ flex: 1, fontSize: 28, fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 15, marginLeft: generalPadding }}>
                               {categoryName}
                         </Text>
                   </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>)}
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
```

I've tried `height: "100%"` for the ScrollView, but that didn't achieve the desired height.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I was able to solve this by wrapping the content in a View with height of 100%.